# script choose 2 files but post only 1

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem when using "Bootstrap File Input" in order to upload files (http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)

If i click BROWSE and choose file and than i click again BROWSE and choose another file than i see 2 files in the preview area i, but when i post the form i get only 1.

Why is that?

HTML

```
<input id="files" name='file[]' type="file" multiple class="file" data-overwrite-initial="false" data-min-file-count="2">
```

The scripts:

```
<link href="bootstrap-file_input/css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/bootstrap-file_input/js/fileinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$("#files").fileinput({
    theme: 'fa',
    uploadUrl: '#', // you must set a valid URL here else you will get an error
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'zip', 'rar', 'csv', 'doc', 'docx', 'txt', 'pdf', 'xml', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
    overwriteInitial: true,
    showUpload: false,
    showUploadedThumbs: false,
//  allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "bmp"],
    maxFileSize: 3000,
    maxFilesNum: 10,
    dropZoneEnabled: false
}); 
</script>
```

PHP

```
if ($_POST) { 
     var_dump ($_FILES); 
}
```

Comment: Could it be something to do with `overwriteInitial: true`?

Comment: @RamRaider - no, i tried to change and still not working...